# KineticJS - How to send image to back after it has loaded (items get loaded before appear infront)

Tags: html, kineticjs

With KineticJS How do I send image to back after it has loaded (items get loaded before appear infront).

I'm loading a background Kinetic.Image and some text objects onto a layer.

Which ever order I put the calls in, the image is always at the front, when I want it at the back of the layer.

Any advice on how I should do this?

Thanks

Comment: how many layers do you have? also, can you show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all the items are in the same layer, you would do something like:

```
 image.moveToBottom();
 layer.draw();
 stage.draw(); //this one is not necessary really but threw it in just in case.
```

this would go in the onload function of your image (at the end).